# bigcommerce theme show all items

Tags: html, bigcommerce

Im working with Big Commerce here and I'm looking to create a page that lists all the products within the website, sort of a "see it all" page. Ive tried working with the         %%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%% and %%Panel.HomeNewProducts%% but with no luck. Is there some code that I can use to pull up all the items on my page?

The url is http://church-furniture-store.mybigcommerce.com/see-it-all/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a another simple way to show all the shop products in bigcommerce. Use this /categories.

Answer (score 0):

Assign all of your products to an "All Products" category. Create a separate category page template if you need to use a display display.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there who wants a custom *All Products* page and is having as much trouble with it as I did -- here's a tip:

Use the /categories url mentioned above as your *All Products* page. The /categories url uses the `category.html` template, so create a separate file for *All Products* content and then put something like this in `category.html`:

```
{{#if category.name }}
  {{> components/custom/product-category }}
{{else}}
  {{> components/custom/all-products }}
{{/if}}
```

The /categories page doesn't have a `category.name` value, so it'll display your custom *All Products* content. And of course all product categories do have a name so they'll display the regular *Product Category* content.